# How to tell the position of a menu item in VB6?

Tags: windows, winapi, vb6, menu, position

I am using Visual Basic 6 (please don't laugh), and I would like to dynamically position a control, at runtime, in a position based upon the position of one of the "top level" menu items (such as "File", "Edit", "View").

Unfortunately, VB's Menu control (which is the type of control that these "File", "Edit", etc. things are) does not have any properties like "Top", "Left", "Height", or "Width".

I could just experiment, eyeballing it, and eventually arrive at numbers that I'll hardcode, but for various reasons I would prefer that the code actually figure out where the control should go.

I am thinking that perhaps there is some Windows API call that I can use to figure out the position of the Menu control?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** In case it matters, this is on an MDI form.

**Edit #2:**

OK, answering my own question:

You can get the position of each item on the main menu bar via the GetMenuBarInfo function, such as:

```
    Dim mbi as MENUBARINFO
    mbi.cbSize = LenB(mbi)
    GetMenuBarInfo Me.hWnd, OBJID_MENU, lMenuNumber, mbi
```

Where "lMenuNumber" is 1 for the first (e.g. "File"), 2 for the second (e.g. "Edit"), etc.

That mbi struct has an rcBar member, which is the coordinates of the rectangle where that menu item is.

Unfortunately, it's in absolute coordinates relative to the screen, not relative to the MDI form.  So, get the mbi the one you're interested in and of the first, and subtract.

Plus, the position as given in the mbi is in pixels, so convert as necessary to twips or whatever.

Comment: by position do you refer to 1st, 2nd etc or its coordinates?

Comment: Coordinates.  I want to figure out the top, left, etc.

Comment: Please don't do this. Put your control somewhere other than on the menu bar. The menu bar is for menus.

Comment: Thank you David, but the control that I'm putting there is a menu.  I am replacing VB6's built-in menus with a third party popup menu control, due to an inherent limitation in VB6.  I need to figure out where to tell that popup menu to pop open, so that it is in the same place as the built-in menu would be.

Comment: I actually did attempt to post it as an answer, and was told that new users cannot answer their own question until eight hours have passed.  So, I edited my question instead.  I'll try to post it now, again, though.

Comment: Now it lets me post it, but won't let me accept it for another 23 hours.  Christ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, answering my own question:

You can get the position of each item on the main menu bar via the GetMenuBarInfo function, such as:

```
    Dim mbi as MENUBARINFO
    mbi.cbSize = LenB(mbi)
    GetMenuBarInfo Me.hWnd, OBJID_MENU, lMenuNumber, mbi
```

Where "lMenuNumber" is 1 for the first (e.g. "File"), 2 for the second (e.g. "Edit"), etc.

That mbi struct has an rcBar member, which is the coordinates of the rectangle where that menu item is.

Unfortunately, it's in absolute coordinates relative to the screen, not relative to the MDI form.  So, get the mbi the one you're interested in and of the first, and subtract.

Plus, the position as given in the mbi is in pixels, so convert as necessary to twips or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of doomed.  Standard menus will vary in appearance and width with the version of Windows and the user's settings for UI fonts and such.  For all we know Windows Next/8 may put them along the left side of the window!

If this information were meant to be used it would be available.

Perhaps if you could explain more about what you are trying to do with your UI we might have alternative suggestions.

Comment: That's a good point, but frankly not one that I am concerned with.  I have all sorts of purity issues that arise due to the fact that I'm using an ancient development environment, which I have to essentially ignore in the name of simply getting something that works.  The idea that Microsoft might come out with a new OS which has menus on the left is the least of my concerns.

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize that "return" causes the post to happen instead of a line feed.  Here's what I was going to continue saying:

The reason I'm doing it is because VB6 imposes a limit of 255 controls per form, and we've hit that limit, mainly due to having something like 230 menu items, each of which counts as a control.

So, I got a third party popup menu control, which will count as 1 instead of 230 or whatever, and I want to tell it to pop open in the appropriate location when the user clicks "File" or "Edit" or whatever.

Comment: I can't image dealing with 255 menus without control arrays. I usually name main menu `mnuMain(0)`, `mnuMain(1)`, ... and the *File* popup menus are `mnuFile(0)`, `mnuFile(1)`, ... and then on *Edit* are `mnuEdit(0)`, `mnuEdit(1)`, etc.